# Matrix Equation $A^* B A = C $ solved for $A$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations

Is there a standardized way to solve

$A^* B A = C $

for $A$ if $A$ is a complex and square matrice, and $B$ and $C$ are real-valued and square matrices. $A^*$ is the conjugate transpose of $A$.

Is there a special name for such kinds of equations?

Edit:

Information that might help: The Matrix B and C are conjugate transpose auto-correlation matrices

$B^* = b \cdot b^*  \\
C^* = c \cdot c^*
$

Comment: Use [Kronecker product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product) with the classical transformation you will find there : $\displaystyle \left(\mathbf {A^*} ^{\textsf {T}}\otimes \mathbf {A} \right)\,\operatorname {vec} (\mathbf {B} )=\operatorname {vec} (\mathbf {A^*BA} )=\operatorname {vec} (\mathbf {C} )$

Comment: Great, Thank you! So it would reduce the problem to solve ($A^∗⊗A)=vec(C)vec(B)^{-1}$ for $A$ ? Is there a trick?

Comment: No you cannot do $vec(B)^{-1}$ because $vec(B)$ is a vector.

Comment: Okay yes, obviously. So how would I get $A$?

Comment: I don't say it is obvious from there to find such a $A$ but at least, in this, way all the unknowns are grouped. If I were you, I would consider first the low dimensional cases beginning by $n=2$...

Comment: If $B$ and $C$ are positive self-adjoint then there is a way. Can you assume that?

Comment: Yes, I can assume that.

Comment: Chrystomath, I have to say I am not a mathematician, but an engineer. I continued by diagonalizing the two hermitian matrices. $A^* Q_1 D_1 Q_1^* A = Q_2 D_2 Q_2$, where $Q_{1,2}$ are the matrices of the eigenvectors and $D_{1,2}$ are the diagonal matrices with the eigenvalues. I guess from there I could solve for A. Is that step correct?

Comment: @ssack I didn't get your message because you forgot to put the @ sign.

Answer (score 0):

If $B,C$ are positive definite self-adjoint matrices, then they have unique Cholesky decomposition $B=L_BL^*_B$, $C=L_CL_C^*$. Substituting into the equation $$A^*L_BL_B^*A=L_CL_C^*$$ $$\therefore L_B^*A=UL_C^*$$ $$A=L_B^{-*}UL_C^*$$ where $U$ is any unitary matrix.